# Sublime terminus console closes after executing program/hitting bugs/inactivity

Tags: sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm using terminus in sublime to open/develop in a zsh but as of about a month ago, my shells automatically close when they become inactive (hit a bug, or successfully execute a program). This is making it difficult to debug/work through my scripts.

Any reason why this started happening recently / can I edit the settings to prevent them from closing? Thank you!

terminus settings

```
{
    // the default config, either a single config name or a platform
    // specific dict
    "default_config": {
        "linux": null,    // login shell
        "osx": null,      // login shell
        "windows": "Command Prompt"
    },
    // a list of available shells to execute
    "shell_configs": [
        {
            "name": "Bash",
            "cmd": ["bash", "-i", "-l"],
            "env": {},
            "enable": true,
            "platforms": ["linux", "osx"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Zsh",
            "cmd": ["zsh", "-i", "-l"],
            "env": {},
            "enable": true,
            "platforms": ["linux", "osx"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Command Prompt",
            "cmd": "cmd.exe",
            "env": {},
            "enable": true,
            "platforms": ["windows"]
        },
        {
            "name": "PowerShell Core",
            "cmd": "pwsh.exe",
            "env": {},
            "enable": true,
            "platforms": ["windows"]
        },
        {
            "name": "PowerShell",
            "cmd": "powershell.exe",
            "env": {},
            "enable": true,
            "platforms": ["windows"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Cmder",
            "cmd": ["cmd.exe", "/k", "%CMDER_ROOT%\\vendor\\init.bat"],
            "env": {},
            "enable": false,
            "platforms": ["windows"]
        },
        {
            "name": "WSL Login Shell",
            "cmd": "wsl.exe",
            "env": {},
            "enable": true,
            "platforms": ["windows"]
        }
    ],

    // Note: for unix users, you will get better 256 color experience
    // if you also set "unix_term" to "xterm-256color"
    // 256 color is not working on Windows because of upstream winpty's issue
    // https://github.com/rprichard/winpty/issues/108
    "256color": false,

    // brighten bold text
    "brighten_bold_text": true,

    // the default TERM variable of unix system. Possible values are
    // "linux", "xterm" and "xterm-256color".
    // However, please aware that not all xterm features are supported.
    "unix_term": "linux",

    // the default LANG variable of unix system.
    "unix_lang": "en_US.UTF-8",

    // number of lines kept in scrollback history
    // decreasing this value may improve performance
    "scrollback_history_size": 10000,

    // set a minimum or maximum terminal width in characters
    "min_columns": 20,
    "max_columns": 500,

    // force the terminal size
    "size": [null, null],

    // Windows and Linux only
    // use ctrl+c to copy
    // use ctrl+v to paste  (use ctrl+alt+v to send ctrl+v instead)
    // use ctrl+pagedown/pageup to change tabs
    "natural_keyboard": true,

    // Terminus sends all keybinds of the form `ctrl+[a-z]` to the terminal process
    // directly. Windows and Linux users sometimes may want to preserve some of such
    // keybinds. (only keybinds listed below are supported, open an issue for a specific
    // keybind if it is not in the list)
    "preserve_keys" : [
        // "ctrl+k"   // there are a number of shortcuts with "ctrl+k" prefix.
        // "ctrl+p"   // to show Go to Anything
    ],

    // the name of the theme
    // the theme could be either "classic", "adaptive", "user" or any predefined themes
    // listed in the command `Terminus Utilities: Select Theme`.
    // For Sublime Text before 4096, the adaptive theme will fallback to the classic theme.
    "theme": "adaptive",

    // change `theme` to "user" if you want to use customized theme
    // see https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/color_schemes.html#colors for the
    // available colors
    "user_theme_colors": {
        // "background": "#262626",
        // "foreground": "#ffffff",
        // "caret": "white",
        // "block_caret": "white",
        // "selection": "#444444",
        // "selection_foreground": "#ffffff"
        // "black": "#000000",
        // "red": "#cd0000",
        // "green": "#00cd00",
        // "brown": "#cdcd00",
        // "blue": "#0000ee",
        // "magenta": "#cd00cd",
        // "cyan": "#00cdcd",
        // "white": "#e5e5e5",
        // "light_black": "#7f7f7f",
        // "light_red": "#ff0000",
        // "light_green": "#00ff00",
        // "light_brown": "#ffff00",
        // "light_blue": "#5c5cff",
        // "light_magenta": "#ff00ff",
        // "light_cyan": "#00ffff",
        // "light_white": "#ffffff"
    },

    "view_settings": {
        // these are extra view settings which are passed to the terminus_view,
        // you could change settings like "font_face", "font_size" and paddings.
    },

    // reactivate terminals when window starts
    "reactivate_terminals": true,

    "debug": false
}
```

{
"view_settings": {
"font_size": 10
},

```
 "shell_configs":[
    {
        "name": "Zsh",
        "cmd": ["zsh", "-i", "-l"],
        "env": {},
        "enable": true,
        "default":true,
        "platforms": ["linux", "osx"]
    }
]
```

}